# In Marketing Cloud Is it possible to select all rows from a data extension where a field value is unique - ie an ID field

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, unique-field

I have a DE which has a number of rows of data (with a number of columns)

ID    Name    date    email
1     ABC     1234    @gmail

1     ABC     5678    @gmail

2     DEF     9101    @yahoo

3     GHI     1112    @yahoo

I want to run a query where I select all the rows where the ID value is unique

So the output would be

ID    Name    date    email
2     DEF     9101    @yahoo

3     GHI     1112    @yahoo

I do not want the ID = 1 value as the value is not unique - it appears twice, and both the Group By and Distinct function will return a value and only removes the duplicates

ID    Name    date    email
1     ABC     1234    @gmail

2     DEF     9101    @yahoo

3     GHI     1112    @yahoo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were mostly there with the GROUP BY. You would just need to add another query above that to pull only those with a count of 1.

See below sample:

```sql
Select b.ID
FROM (
  SELECT a.ID,
  COUNT(a.ID) as cnt
  FROM [myDE] a
  GROUP BY a.ID
) b
WHERE b.cnt = 1
```

This will only return those that have a single entry for ID.

---

**EDIT FROM COMMENT**:

For more fields, you can use the aggregate function MAX() on the other fields to remove the need to include them in the GROUP BY statement. Since there is only 1 entry for these records, there is no worry about mixed records.

something like:

```sql
Select b.ID, b.Name, b.date, b.email
FROM (
  SELECT a.ID, 
  MAX(a.Name) as Name,
  MAX(a.date) as date,
  MAX(a.email) as email,
  COUNT(a.ID) as cnt
  FROM [myDE] a
  GROUP BY a.ID
) b
WHERE b.cnt = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for this Gortonington - is it possible to select  additional columns at the same time ie Select b.ID, b.Name, b.Date, b.Email - The reason I ask is that when I try to grab additional columns from my DE I get the error - Invalid column name 'column_name'

Comment: @Ap12345 - added detail on getting the other columns inside of my answer

Comment: Thanks mate, I got it all worked out now, thanks for the help